# How do I make a link using keybindins, and selected text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking for a way to <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd>, that popups a box to to insert a link, on the selected text. Just like the StackExchange editor, I'm using right now!

the links are preferably valid `html`, and if I can choose both `MarkDown` and valid `html`, then that would be awesome!

I could not find it anywhere on SO, or the interwebs.

What i have done before:

```
$("#mark").click(function () {
   var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
   var newNode = document.createElement('mark');
   range.surroundContents(newNode);    
   return false;  
});
```

Button:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="mark">mark</a>
```

When clicking the `mark` button it would apply the HTML `mark` tag to the

`<mark>selected text</mark>`

I want the same feaute as i the stackexchange editor:<kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd>get this box:

[image]

---

**EDIT**

My new code :

While playing with the promptbox using javascript<sup>[1]</sup>, i managed to get it the way I want it.

```
<button onclick="link()">Link</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function link() {
    var link = prompt("Insert hyperlink", "http://");
    var title = prompt("Insert hyperlink title", "title");
    var name = prompt("Insert hyperlink name", "name");
    
    if (link != null) {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
        "\<a href=\"" + link + "\" title=\" " + title + " \"> " + name + " </a>";
    }
}
</script>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/blade1989/1q9bmy9w/1/)

Trying to get to work:

- To get the content of the html `title` tag, when inserting the link.

  example:

  <a href="https://www.example.nl/example" title="*link*: *title*">*title*</a>

Reference:

1. [Tryit Editor v2.2](http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_prompt)

Comment: What do you need help with? Displaying the box on the keypress? Validating the links? Inserting the links in your editor? What have you tried/made so far?

Comment: @Drown The actual code. I have tried to search the web for it, but no luck. I'm a js/jquery beginner. Same features as the Stackechange editor regarding creating links. I have made an editor, that can apply green color on selected text, using `span` by clicking a button, but creating a link is a bit different.

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery, you can use an on `keydown` trigger to capture the keys that were pressed, like so :

```
$('#your_textarea').on('keydown', function(e){
    //Check if it was CTRL-L
    if(e.keyCode == 76 && e.ctrlKey)
    {
        var link = prompt("Enter a link : ");
    }
});
```

Now, the link the user entered is in the `link`variable. You can do what you want with it (ex: append it to the editor's textarea).

**Note** : You have to use the `keydown`event, the `keypressed`and `keyup`events will not work for this.

Here's a fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/js1p5h9n/

Comment: Is the fiddle working for you? What have you tried? Edit your question to include your new code.

Comment: done posted my new code. As for your code. I have minimal knowledge of `jquery`. Basically poked it with a stick, wasn't working, so, gave up.